# What does this error mean: invalid ELF header

Tags: python, lxml

I'm getting an `IMPORT ERROR` with the following error message in Django debug mode `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/lxml-2.3-py2.6-win32.egg/lxml/objectify.pyd: invalid ELF header`

What does this mean and how do I fix it? Google is revealing not very much at the moment. This error is coming from this [package](https://github.com/tschellenbach/DjangoOpenInviter) I am using in my Django app

**Update**
I'm using ubuntu and Python2.6

Comment: You are trying to import a win32-compiled "egg" on Linux.

Comment: Please, add what platform are you on and what version of python you use.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error means the `objectify.pyd` is not a valid shared library. You seem to have `lxml` compiled for different version of python from what you are running.

Guessing from the path, the fact that 'ELF' is an object (shared and executable) format used on unices and the package has -win32 in it's name you are probably trying to use windows build on linux.

Comment: That's quite odd isn't it. So how can I replace it with the linux version?

Comment: Probably `apt-get install python-lxml` or the like.

Comment: @Ignacio I saw one of your earlier posts and tried `apt-get install python-lxml` already. This is like the aftermath

Comment: Well, remove the egg that has been built for the wrong OS then.

Comment: I get a similar problem with another library. As I used macos, python use native lib witch is no compatible with azure cloud function Linux os. I used a python docker image to build .python_packages dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

simply do a

```
pip install -U lxml
```

I had the same error, and it found an update to the existing installation and fixed it for me.

You might have to prefix sudo depending upon whether you are using a Virtual Environment or not

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was trying to install tf 1.2 with venv built with python 3.6+. the issue was incompatible dependencies. For starters, please check if you are not doing that mistake by checking tested builds here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source?hl=en#tested_build_configurations