# I want to install pyv8 for using python-Wappalyzer but I cant fix this error

Tags: python, elf, pyv8

at the first I ran this:

```
pip install -e git://github.com/brokenseal/PyV8-OS-X#egg=pyv8
```

this message showed :

```
Obtaining pyv8 from git+git://github.com/brokenseal/PyV8-OS-X#egg=pyv8
Updating ./src/pyv8 clone
Running setup.py egg_info for package pyv8

Installing collected packages: pyv8
Running setup.py develop for pyv8
Checking .pth file support in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
/usr/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST PASSED: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ appears to support   .pth files

Creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyV8.egg-link (link to .)
PyV8 0.8 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /root/src/pyv8
Successfully installed pyv8
Cleaning up...
```

I used this code for run python-Wappalyzer :

```
 from wappalyzer import Wappalyzer
```

error was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wappalyzer/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from pyv8 import PyV8
File "/root/src/pyv8/pyv8/PyV8.py", line 17, in <module>
import _PyV8
ImportError: /root/src/pyv8/pyv8/_PyV8.so: invalid ELF header
```

I installed lxml and Requests but not fixed.
how can I fix this problem .I ran this code in ubuntu 14.4 and kali but had same problem.

Comment: You can find some guidance towards the error you're getting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713731/what-does-this-error-mean-invalid-elf-header).

Comment: I used this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713731/what-does-this-error-mean-invalid-elf-header?lq=1) but not worked

Comment: I used this Guide for installing "PyV8" : [Importing PyV8 Engine into Python 2.7, the easy way](http://www.wikisecure.net/importing-pyv8-engine-into-python-v2-7-the-easy-way/) this is good for me :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you downloaded wrong binary (32 bit, 64 bit) for `PyV8`

FOR 32 bit arch Use these steps:

```
$ wget -c "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emmetio/pyv8-binaries/master/pyv8-linux32.zip"
$ unzip pyv8-linux32.zip
$ sudo cp *PyV8* /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

---

For 64 bit arch Use these steps:

```
$ wget -c "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emmetio/pyv8-binaries/master/pyv8-linux64.zip"
$ unzip pyv8-linux64.zip
$ rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/*PyV8*
$ sudo cp *PyV8* /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```