# Invalid ELF header tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I first tried installing tensorflow via the following:

```
user@WS1:~/July 2016$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

user@WS1:~/July 2016$ pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

Then I tried using a (slightly modified version for linux and tensorflow 0.9.0) solution from [iRapha here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/135):

```
user@WS1:~/July 2016$ wget https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

user@WS1:~/July 2016$ pip install tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Then I tried to test whether tensorflow was successfully installed. The following output shows that there is an 'invalid ELF header' error.

```
user@WS1:~/July 2016$ python
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/export/mlrg/caugusta/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages   /tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/export/mlrg/caugusta/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/export/mlrg/caugusta/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/export/mlrg/caugusta/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /export/mlrg/caugusta/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: invalid ELF header
```

I've checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713731/what-does-this-error-mean-invalid-elf-header). Based on that answer, I tried:

```
user@WS1:~July 2016$ pip install tensorflow
```

Everything says that tensorflow installed successfully, but when I import it in python I get that invalid ELF header error. Anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: are you sure that tensorflow is even available with `pip`? I can't find it with a `pip search tensorflow`

Comment: That's a potential problem, but I tried installing three different ways and all ways said that tensorflow was installed successfully.

Comment: did the current answer respond your question? Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 10):

This could happen if you have install tensorflow package which does not match your platform.

An extreme example would be installing the mac platform package (as seen below) on linux.

```
export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Just make sure you use the correct platform.