# Running a python script results in invalid ELF header error on tensorflow wrapper?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm getting an error on

> /usr/pointNet/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so:
> invalid ELF header

I've tf 1.4
Ubuntu 20.04
Also, I've tried import tensorflow, which fails. Any idea what this error msg signifies?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid ELF header tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579190/invalid-elf-header-tensorflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was downloading NVIDIA driver and CUDA on UBUNTU without realizing that I was working on WSL2.
For WSL2, the driver should be installed on windows only. The following link helped: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html